# Create a Wordpressloop with two posts of the next page

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I need to create a wordpress-site which shows 5 posts on the front and in a different loop: 2 posts of the next page. These show up if you visit the second page. Do you have any ideas? I wanna show "More articles" by displaying "older" posts in a different loop.

Thanks

Comment: If you still want an answer, you should move your question to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ - more experts there. Either flag your question for moderator attention, or delete it here yourself and repost it on WP.SE

Answer (score 0):

For the first page, limit your listing to 5 posts per page in wordpress settings.

Then you create the second page and apply a page template in witch you have made a custom query to fetch 2 posts.

```
  $cat = get_cat_ID($category);
  $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
  $post_per_page = 2; // -1 shows all posts
  $do_not_show_stickies = 1; // 0 to show stickies
  $args=array(
  'category__in' => array($cat),
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'paged' => $paged,
  'posts_per_page' => $post_per_page,
  'caller_get_posts' => $do_not_show_stickies
  );
  $temp = $wp_query;  // assign orginal query to temp variable for later use   
  $wp_query = null;
  $wp_query = new WP_Query($args); 

  if( have_posts() ) : 
  ...
```

To read more, see [Wordpress Codex Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#A_Page_of_Posts)

Comment: Sorry I don't get it :-) I want to create two loops on the index.php. The first one shows the 5 posts (like you said) and the second shows the post of the next page in short form. Is it possible with wordpress?